# Git - Copy the content of a branch (remote repo) to a local branch

Tags: git

I am willing to copy the content of a branch from a remote repo to a local branch (repo).

I've tried several solutions, as well as the below one, but none worked :

```
git remote add fork <url of fork>
git fetch fork
git checkout -b fork_branch fork/<branch>
```

Comment: Offhand this seems right. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <url>
```